# If either or both condition true

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to get array values if either or both condition returns true for example:

```
    $emailarr = array('arsalan@gmail.com', 'aquarious@yahoo.com', 'imran@google.com');    
foreach ($emailarr as $email) {
   if ($email !== 'aquarious@yahoo.com' || 'imran@google.com'){
    echo 'Email Send to '. $email   ;
   }   
}
```

what actually i need is

```
if only (aquarious@yahoo.com) return true
If only (imran@google.com)    return true
if both (aquarious@yahoo.com and imran@google.com) return true
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: My best advice is to practice and read php.net before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the "both" condition, you only need the "either".

You can also use `if (in_array($email, array(email1, email2...)) {...}`

(In a foreach, "both" won't happen in the same iteration.)

Answer (score 1):

Just change your logic to this:

```
if ($email == 'aquarious@yahoo.com' || $email ==  'imran@google.com'){
    echo 'Email Send to '. $email   ;
}
```

Output:

```
Email Send to aquarious@yahoo.com
Email Send to imran@google.com
```

Comment: what if i don't need both values but only arsalan@gmail.com?

Comment: @user3501918 With the OR condition only one has to be true, so your totally fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do, but one way to achieve what you need is:

```
$emails = ['arsalan@gmail.com', 'aquarious@yahoo.com', 'imran@google.com'];

if (count($emails) == 1) {
    if (in_array('aquarious@yahoo.com', $emails)) {
        return true;
    } else if (in_array('imran@google.com', $emails)) {
        return true;
    }
} else if ((count($emails) == 2) && (in_array('aquarious@yahoo.com', $emails)) && (in_array('imran@google.com', $emails))) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Also, is not a good practice to add the type of object to a variable name like you did in "$email_arrays"; $emails is just fine.